# Can't import `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, overriding

I have extended my class from `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` according to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-rest/2.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.html#configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration)) it has `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` method which can be implemented but when I try to override this method I can't import it :| 
Can anybody tell me Why this problem occurred?

**EDIT** : according to current version `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` method is not avialble.. so what method should I used instead of this?

Here is my code

**MSARepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
public class MSARepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MSARepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${static.path}")
    private String staticPath;

//    @Bean
//    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
//        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
//    }
  @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setBasePath("/api");
       // config.exposeIdsFor(User.class,Order.class,HeroRating.class,RiderLocation.class,OrderItem.class,Address.class,ShopDetail.class,PromoCode.class,RiderDuty.class,Criteria.class,Setting.class);
        config.setReturnBodyForPutAndPost(true);
        config.setReturnBodyOnCreate(true);
        config.setReturnBodyOnUpdate(true);
    }

    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
     if(staticPath != null) {
          LOG.info("Serving static content from " + staticPath);
          registry.addResourceHandler("/photos/**").addResourceLocations("file:" + staticPath+"photos/");
           registry.addResourceHandler("/").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```

**Error**
It gives an error on `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` to remove override annotation

**ErrorMessage**

```
The method configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration) of type MSARepositoryRestMvcConfiguration must override or implement a supertype method
```

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct version of the documentation? this is the documentation of the current api https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.html and I can't find that method there.

Comment: @Stultuske Ohh.. I think this  method is now eliminated

Comment: @Stultuske can you tell me what merthod should I sued ? instead of this

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with those classes, so I can't be of much help there.

Comment: @Stultuske Okay Thanks

Comment: you could always change your dependency to that older version of Spring

Comment: @Stultuske downgrading to a much older version instead of taking a few minutes for googling and reading the documentation is a pretty bad advice, IMHO.

Comment: @MarcTarin true, which is why I didn't post it as an answer. But, seeing as he's using that old documentation, there is a possibility he was required to use that version. not every company updates versions (even though they should) and there are some that will stay on old versions. if that's the case, the latest fix won't help either

Comment: @Stultuske point taken. But since the OP asked about what method to use in the current version, I simply assumed he had no such constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to current version of spring document this method is not available so instead of `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration'  we can override following method

```
@Configuration
public class MSARepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
        public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
            RepositoryRestConfiguration config = super.config();
            config.setBasePath("/api");
            config.exposeIdsFor(User.class);
            return config; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the current `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` definition at [Interface RepositoryRestConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestConfigurer.html).

Example form https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-serialize-entity-id:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Person.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the current reference documentation, [Configuring Spring Data REST](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.configuration):

> To customize the configuration, register a RepositoryRestConfigurer (or extend RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter) and implement or override the configure…-methods relevant to your use case.

SDR configuration outside of `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` was addressed in [DATAREST-621](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-621) and RepositoryRestConfigurer was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/12121f842ef4c481af5b84e4d2a5d625baaee178).